# Android :Unable to reload the fragments with the updated content from the server

Tags: android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a Fragment as the container having a tablayout with a viewpager having 2 tab fragment. Inside the main container fragment i have a toolbar with a custom button which is onclicking updates the content in the tab fragment by hitting the webservice.

This the code for the container fragment.

```
public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {

TabLayout tabLayout = null;
ViewPager viewPagerNotifications = null;

public NotificationsFragment()
 {
     // Required empty public constructor
}

public static NotificationsFragment newInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    NotificationsFragment fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, null);

    final Button mButton_right = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Button_right);
    mButton_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final Button mButton_alerts = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Button_alerts);
    mButton_alerts.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TabLayout_notifications);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Symptoms"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Diagnosis"));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(8);
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.textColorPrimary),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));

    ViewCompat.setElevation(tabLayout, 5f);

    viewPagerNotifications = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagernotifications);


    final NotificationPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new NotificationPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPagerNotifications.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    viewPagerNotifications.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    viewPagerNotifications.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            Log.e("notif","onpageselected"+position);


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPagerNotifications.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            switch (tab.getPosition())
            {
                case 0:
                    mButton_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mButton_alerts.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                   /* LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
                    Intent i = new Intent("TAG_REFRESH");
                    lbm.sendBroadcast(i);*/

                    break;

                case 1:
                    mButton_right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mButton_alerts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });




    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

}

This is the code for Pager Adapter class

```
public class NotificationPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

final int Illness = 1;
final int Symptoms = 0;

int numOfTabs;

SymptomsTabFragment symptomsTabFragment;
IllnessTabFragment illnessTabFragment;


public NotificationPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int numOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numOfTabs=numOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position)
    {
        case Symptoms:
           symptomsTabFragment = new SymptomsTabFragment();
            return symptomsTabFragment;

        case Illness:
             illnessTabFragment= new IllnessTabFragment();
            return illnessTabFragment;


    }
    return null;
}


  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return numOfTabs;
  }
}
```

This is the Code of the 1st Tab Fragment

```
 public class SymptomsTabFragment extends Fragment {

@Bind(R.id.recycler_view_notificationsSymptoms)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView_notificationSymptoms;


NetworkStatus mNetworkStatus = null;

static AlertDialog mShowDialog = null;

Button mButton_right;

ArrayList<NotificationSymptomdata> notificationSymptoms = null;
ArrayList<NotificationSymptomdata> notificationSymptomid = null;
ArrayList<String> notificationSettingID = null;
ArrayList<NotificationSymptomdata> isNotification = null;


public SymptomsTabFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static SymptomsTabFragment newInstance() {
    SymptomsTabFragment fragment = new SymptomsTabFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e("stb", "oncreate");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_symptoms_tab, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    mButton_right = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Button_right);


    Log.e("stb", "oncreateview");


    Toolbar.LayoutParams params = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(marginInDp(80), marginInDp(50));
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    params.setMargins(0, 0, marginInDp(20), 0);
    mButton_right.setLayoutParams(params);
    mButton_right.setBackgroundResource(0);
    mButton_right.setTag(1);
    mButton_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mButton_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final int status = (Integer) v.getTag();
            if (status == 1) {
                mButton_right.setText("Select All");
                v.setTag(0);

            } else {

                mButton_right.setText("DeSelect All");
                v.setTag(1);
            }

            if (mButton_right.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select All")) {


                ArrayList<UpdateNotificationRequestData> Updatenoti;

                Log.e("stb", "onclick");

                UpdateNotificationsRequestModel requestModel = new UpdateNotificationsRequestModel();
                requestModel.setUserID(AppPreferences.readString(getActivity(), AppPreferenceNames.sUserid, ""));
                requestModel.setAppVersion(CommonUtils.APP_VERSION);
                requestModel.setDeviceInfo(CommonUtils.DeviceInfo);
                requestModel.setDeviceTypeID(CommonUtils.DEVICE_TYPE_ID);

                Updatenoti = new ArrayList<UpdateNotificationRequestData>();
                UpdateNotificationRequestData requestData;
                for (int i = 0; i < notificationSymptoms.size(); i++) {
                    requestData = new UpdateNotificationRequestData();
                    requestData.setIsNotification("1");
                    requestData.setNotificationSettingID(notificationSymptoms.get(i).getNotificationSettingID());
                    Updatenoti.add(requestData);
                }

                requestModel.setUpdateNotification(Updatenoti);

                if (mNetworkStatus.isNetWorkAvailable(getActivity()) == true) {
                    update_notifications(requestModel);

                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "No Network Available. Please connect to network");
                }

            } else if (mButton_right.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("DeSelect All")) {

                ArrayList<UpdateNotificationRequestData> Updatenoti;

                Log.e("stb", "onclick");

                UpdateNotificationsRequestModel requestModel = new UpdateNotificationsRequestModel();
                requestModel.setUserID(AppPreferences.readString(getActivity(), AppPreferenceNames.sUserid, ""));
                requestModel.setAppVersion(CommonUtils.APP_VERSION);
                requestModel.setDeviceInfo(CommonUtils.DeviceInfo);
                requestModel.setDeviceTypeID(CommonUtils.DEVICE_TYPE_ID);

                Updatenoti = new ArrayList<UpdateNotificationRequestData>();
                UpdateNotificationRequestData requestData;
                for (int i = 0; i < notificationSymptoms.size(); i++) {
                    requestData = new UpdateNotificationRequestData();
                    requestData.setIsNotification("0");
                    requestData.setNotificationSettingID(notificationSymptoms.get(i).getNotificationSettingID());
                    Updatenoti.add(requestData);
                }

                requestModel.setUpdateNotification(Updatenoti);

                if (mNetworkStatus.isNetWorkAvailable(getActivity()) == true) {
                    update_notifications(requestModel);
                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "No Network Available. Please connect to network");
                }


            }


        }
    });


    notificationSymptoms = new ArrayList<>();
    notificationSymptomid = new ArrayList<>();
    notificationSettingID = new ArrayList<>();
    isNotification = new ArrayList<>();

    mNetworkStatus = new NetworkStatus(getActivity());


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}


/**
 * Used to set margin value programmatically
 *
 * @param sizeInDP
 * @return
 */
private int marginInDp(int sizeInDP) {
    int marginInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, sizeInDP, getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());
    return marginInDp;
}


/**
 * Update the notification settings
 */
public void update_notifications(UpdateNotificationsRequestModel object) {
    /**
     * Start the progress Bar.
     */
    CommonUtils.show_progressbar(getActivity());

    /**
     * call api
     */

    Call<UpdateNotificationsResponseModel> responsecall = VirusApplication.getRestClient().getAPIService().updateNotifications(object);
    responsecall.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateNotificationsResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<UpdateNotificationsResponseModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            /**
             * Stop the progress Bar
             */
            CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();

            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                //Server Success
                UpdateNotificationsResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
                if (responseModel.getErrorCode().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    //Data Success
                    Log.e("nf", "data success");

                    CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), responseModel.getMessage());

                   // getNotificationSettings();


                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), responseModel.getMessage());

                   // getNotificationSettings();


                }
            } else {

                CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Server Error");

               // getNotificationSettings();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            /**
             * Stop the progress Bar
             */
            CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();


        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.e("stb", "onresume");

  /*  r = new MyReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(r,
            new IntentFilter("TAG_REFRESH"));
        */
       /**
      * Downloads mychildren details.
     */
       if (mNetworkStatus.isNetWorkAvailable(getActivity()) == true) {
          getNotificationSettings();
       } else {
         CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(),                      getString(R.string.network_unavailable));
    }




}


/**
 * Get Notification Settings
 */
public void getNotificationSettings() {

    //hit the getnotifications API to fetch the notification details

    CommonUtils.show_progressbar(getActivity());

    /**
     * Calls WebAPI
     */

    Call<NotificationsModel> notificationsModelCall = VirusApplication.getRestClient().getAPIService().notifications(getNotificationsrequest());
    notificationsModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<NotificationsModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<NotificationsModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            /**
             * Stops the Progresss bar
             */
            CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();

            if (response.isSuccess()) {//Server Success

                NotificationsModel notificationsModel = response.body();
                if (notificationsModel.getErrorCode().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {// Data Success

                    int i = 1;
                    for (NotificationSymptomdata nsymptomsData : notificationsModel.getNotificationSymptomdata()) {
                        notificationSymptoms.add(nsymptomsData);
                        //  aSymptomsID.add(symptomsData.getSymptomID());

                       /* if (edit_child_symptoms_id == symptomsData.getSymptomID()) {
                            illness_selection_position = i;
                        }*/

                        i++;
                    }


                    Log.e("noti", "Symptoms ArraySize-->" + notificationSymptoms.size());

                    if (notificationSymptoms.size() != 0) {
                        NotificationsAdapter notificationsAdapter = new NotificationsAdapter(getActivity(), notificationSymptoms);
                        mRecyclerView_notificationSymptoms.setAdapter(notificationsAdapter);
                        notificationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        LinearLayoutManager SymptomsLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        mRecyclerView_notificationSymptoms.setLayoutManager(SymptomsLayoutManager);
                    }

                    for(int j=0;j<notificationSymptoms.size();j++)
                    {
                        if (notificationSymptoms.get(j).getIsNotification().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                        {
                            mButton_right.setText("DeSelect All");
                        }
                        else
                        if(notificationSymptoms.get(j).getIsNotification().equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
                        {
                            mButton_right.setText("Select All");
                        }
                        else
                        if (notificationSymptoms.get(j).getIsNotification().equalsIgnoreCase("true") || (notificationSymptoms.get(j).getIsNotification().equalsIgnoreCase("false")))
                        {
                            Log.e("ins","coming  here");

                            mButton_right.setText("Select All");
                        }
                    }


                } else { // Data Failure
    //                        CommonUtils.makeToast(AddLogActivity.this,      illnessCategory.getMessage());
                    /**
                     * Stops the Progresss bar
                     */
                    CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();
                    Log.e("noti", "data failure");
                }
            } else {// Server Failure
 //                    CommonUtils.makeToast(AddLogActivity.this, "Server Error");
                /**
                 * Stops the Progresss bar
                 */
                CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();
                Log.e("noti", "server failure");
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            /**
             * Stops the Progresss bar
             */
            CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();
            Log.e("noti", "retrofit failure");

        }
    });


}

/**
 * Request values to Get notifications.
 *
 * @return map object
 */
public Map<String, Object> getNotificationsrequest() {

    Map<String, Object> getChildrenValues = new HashMap<>();
    getChildrenValues.put("appVersion", CommonUtils.APP_VERSION);
    getChildrenValues.put("deviceTypeID", CommonUtils.DEVICE_TYPE_ID);
    getChildrenValues.put("deviceInfo", CommonUtils.DeviceInfo);
    getChildrenValues.put("userID", AppPreferences.readString(getActivity(), AppPreferenceNames.sUserid, ""));

    return getChildrenValues;

   }
 }
```

The problem that im facing here is on click of the mButton_right based on the text of the button i.e "Select all" or "deselect all" i should update the content in my fragment. The call to the webservice on the selection of the respective buttons is happening correctly inside the tab.

But whenever new data is recieved after updation, I am unable to refresh the tab fragment with the new incoming data.
How and where should i call the service to get the updated data and refresh the tab fragment on click of the button? please help!

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing your data of the `Fragment` inside `TabLayout` you should create a function will get called always whenever you change `Fragment` and you can refresh the data  inside that. For more see:

```
 // In activity 
 final Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
        if (currentFragment instanceof MainTabFragment) {
               ((MainTabFragment) currentFragment).doRefresh();
        }
```